# How to get '0' in a count() using pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, pivot

I'm doing a `SELECT` to my Table with a `PIVOT` Statement. 
When it counts the field `MARCA_INCUMP` in columns `[0]` and `[1]` in some years, it does not have records and I need that it shows a Zero(0).
In another year that it has records, it shows without problems.

```
SELECT FECHA_SOLICITUD, GRUPO AS GRUPO, [0], [1], 
    ([0]+[1]) AS TOTAL, ([1]*1.0) / ([0]+[1]) AS PD_REAL
FROM (SELECT MARCA_INCUMP, GRUPO, FECHA_SOLICITUD FROM MyTable) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT (
 COUNT(MARCA_INCUMP)
 FOR MARCA_INCUMP IN ([0], [1]) 
) AS PivotTable 
GROUP BY fecha_solicitud, GRUPO, [0], [1]
ORDER BY FECHA_SOLICITUD, GRUPO ASC;
```

I need this

```
DATE  GRUPO [0] [1] TOTAL           PD
201411  1   0   0   0   0.000000000000
201411  2   30  3   33  0.090909090909
201411  3   89  2   91  0.021978021978
201411  4   82  7   89  0.078651685393
201411  5   185 20  205 0.097560975609
201411  6   129 21  150 0.140000000000
201411  7   70  14  84  0.166666666666
201411  8   40  12  52  0.230769230769
201411  9   38  31  69  0.449275362318
201411  10  10  19  29  0.655172413793
```

and i have this

```
DATE  GRUPO [0] [1] TOTAL           PD
201412  2   37  1   38  0.026315789473
201412  3   83  5   88  0.056818181818
201412  4   78  9   87  0.103448275862
201412  5   207 24  231 0.103896103896
201412  6   117 19  136 0.139705882352
201412  7   75  17  92  0.184782608695
201412  8   30  11  41  0.268292682926
201412  9   35  33  68  0.485294117647
201412  10  8   34  42  0.809523809523
```

Comment: Please provide your input data for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `LEFT JOIN` between a query that returns all possible periods (or groups) and your existing query. If the possible periods are just the month numbers, you can specify those in a `VALUES` clause. If the possible groups are in a different table, just use that table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issues is that `COUNT` is literally counting anything. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL
>   values and duplicates.

So, we need to count only values that are `0` and `1` and `PIVOT` them.

Try the following:

```
SELECT FECHA_SOLICITUD
      ,GRUPO AS GRUPO
      ,[0]
      ,[1]
      ,([0]+[1]) AS TOTAL, ([1]*1.0) / ([0]+[1]) AS PD_REAL
FROM
(
    SELECT GRUPO
          ,FECHA_SOLICITUD 
          ,SUM(IIF(MARCA_INCUMP = 0, 1, 0)) AS [0]
          ,SUM(IIF(MARCA_INCUMP = 1, 1, 0)) AS [1]
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY GRUPO
            ,FECHA_SOLICITUD 
) DS
GROUP BY fecha_solicitud, GRUPO, [0], [1]
ORDER BY FECHA_SOLICITUD, GRUPO ASC;
```